# Do vegans eat honey?

Tags: vegan

We all know that besides what vegetarians don't eat (meat and fish), vegans also don't eat eggs. But do vegans eat honey, and, if not, then what do they consume in place of honey when they have a throat problem? And what if they happen to be also diabetic?

Answer (score 2):

Most people who identify as vegan do not eat honey. Some do.

Hopefully when faced with a throat problem, they consume medicine (which typically is not a problem for diabetics).